# VB6 Label Set hand Cursor

Tags: vb6

How to Set hand Cursor for a Label Control in Visual Basic 6

My label should act like a Link button.

I changed the `ForeColor` to `vbBlue` , Underline Style and so on..

now I have to set the Hand cursor for that Label.. How to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use API calls to get the system hand cursor

Put the following code in a module

```
Public Const IDC_HAND = 32649&
Public Declare Function SetCursor Lib "user32" (ByVal hCursor As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function LoadCursor Lib "user32" Alias "LoadCursorA" (ByVal hInstance As Long, ByVal lpCursorName As Long) As Long
```

and in the MouseMove event of the label, put the following code

```
SetCursor LoadCursor(0, IDC_HAND)
```

Other cursor constants: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Works Great... This is wat i Expected... Thank You @crackalak

Comment: Excellent piece of code, very simple and 100% effective.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to do a custom [`MouseIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235190%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). You will find a hand cursor in the graphics folder of your Visual Studio 6 installation. Here is the code to do it:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
     Label1.MousePointer = vbCustom
     Label1.MouseIcon = LoadPicture("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\Graphics\Cursors\H_POINT.cur")
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 I took the liberty of editing your post to include a link to the VB6 manual topic.

Comment: perfect! the pointer icon pick the default of windows hand icon.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have an ICO or CUR file with a hand cursor, then set that as a custom `MouseIcon` in the designer (also set `MousePointer` to `99 - Custom`).

You can search the web for a free version of the cursor if you don't have it.

Comment: There is an Error like  `Invalid Picture` when i set any cursor, ico, png files i download.. what is quality of the cur or ico or png to be here in vb6 controls..???